# Assign equal spaces in shell script so that no overlapping occurs between multiple output statements in a single line

Tags: linux, shell, sh

So I have a generic logging function which is being used for logging purposes. All the other functions use this generic function where logging is necessary and the statement along with the required paramenters is passed to the logger file.

```
Eg 1: This is what I am getting as output in the log file
Mon Jan 11 18:32:30 UTC 2016 "Function X " "Check File X"    "More info needed"
Mon Jan 11 18:32:30 UTC 2016 "Function Y & A"   "Check File Y&A"   "More info needed"
Mon Jan 11 18:32:30 UTC 2016 "Function Z and A"   "Check File Z"  "More info needed"

Eg 2: What I need
Mon Jan 11 18:32:30 UTC 2016  "Function X "        "Check File X"         "More info needed"
Mon Jan 11 18:32:30 UTC 2016  "Function Y & A"     "Check File Y & A"     "More info needed"
Mon Jan 11 18:32:30 UTC 2016  "Function Z and A"   "Check File Z and A"   "More info needed"
```

I need the Function (), CheckFile & More Info needed with the same spaces but not overlapping each other's space. Need to intend it basically. I tried using \t(Tab Spaces) between them but it isn't helping either. A bigger statement makes the next line start liner as shown in example 1. I am using an echo statement in my generic function to redirect the Date, Function name, File name & a statement all in one line to the logfile.

Comment: It's actually easier to do this in a generic way if your initial format, pre-processing, is tabs. Otherwise, it's hard to distinguish between field separators and regular spaces within a field (be those inside your dates or inside your quoted strings).

Comment: Is your logging function generating the first three fields in that output (the date, function and file strings) or is that part of the input?

Comment: It is basically an 
echo -e "`date` function Name File Name Error string " which gets redirected to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use tabs to separate columns in your output.

Why?

1. It's difficult to know in advance the maximum width for a column. It can be impossible, depending on where the data for each column comes from.
2. Tabs are flexible by default.
3. The output can be processed before viewing.

If you separate your values with tabs, you can filter it through `expand` to force a specific tab width when viewing the file. You can even open it in LibreOffice Calc, and have the columns fall into place due to its tab-separated value support.

If you wanted to, you could write a script to convert the tab-separated columns into a pretty-printed table for viewing. In python this would be easy: read all lines, zip them to get a tuple of columns, get the maximum width of each column, then print all the lines with each column padded to that width.

The greatest advantage of using tabs rather than spaces is that you can always process a tab-separated file and convert it into a format with spaces if you later change your mind, but it is much more difficult to go in the opposite direction.